# Correct memory allocation for tomcat server?

Tags: java, tomcat

My current set has 4 instance of tomcat running on 4 different ports, I am trying to understand the memory allocation for them, it seems the value is confusing me. I need help before that let me put the configuration details here

```
tomcat_+  1604  1603  0 May22 ?        00:03:20 /home/tomcat_mat/jre-9.0.4/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/tomcat_mat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027 -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -Djava.library.path=/usr/tomcat_mat/webapps/imagemeta/WEB-INF/classes -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -classpath /usr/tomcat_mat//bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/tomcat_mat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/tomcat_mat -Dcatalina.home=/usr/tomcat_mat/ -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/tomcat_mat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

tomcat1  22245     1  2 May22 ?        00:50:33 /usr/java/latest/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/tomcat.1/conf/logging.properties -Xms256M -Xmx4000M -Xss256k -XX:MaxPermSize=4000M -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/tomcat.1/common/endorsed -classpath /usr/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/tomcat.1 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/tomcat.1/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

tomcat2   4329     1  1 08:03 ?        00:02:32 /usr/java/latest/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/tomcat.2/conf/logging.properties -Xms256M -Xmx512M -Xss256k -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/tomcat.2/common/endorsed -classpath /usr/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/tomcat.2 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/tomcat.2/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

tomcat3   8799     1  0 08:16 ?        00:00:13 /usr/java/latest/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/tomcat.3/conf/logging.properties -Xms256M -Xmx512M -Xss256k -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/tomcat.3/common/endorsed -classpath /usr/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/tomcat.3 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/tomcat.3/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

tomcat4   9514     1  1 08:17 ?        00:03:09 /usr/java/latest/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/tomcat.4/conf/logging.properties -Xms256M -Xmx512M -Xss256k -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=11099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/tomcat.4/common/endorsed -classpath /usr/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/tomcat.4 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/tomcat.4/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

in-short current allocation tell me

```
tomcat_+ -> -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m
tomcat1  -> -Xms256M -Xmx4000M
tomcat2  -> -Xms256M -Xmx512M 
tomcat3  -> -Xms256M -Xmx512M 
tomcat4  -> -Xms256M -Xmx512M
```

What is this `tomcat_+`, so as per math what is the correct memory allocation for tomcat server is it 2GB or 4GB ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the first is the output of  `ps` and tomcat* is the user name of the process.

`tomcat_+` is the abbreviated name of the real user name (ps prints first 7 chars). Look for the full name by getting the UID:

```
ps -l 1604
grep <UID> /etc/password
```

I guess you have 5 tomcats running, one started from the parent process id 1603. Look what is PID 1603.

Anyway, in ps you see the starting configuration for minimal and maximal heap. That is not the current effective usage of heap in each process.

What is the correct ? Depends on the heap usage of your application.